# How to make logo not to have hover in menu?

Tags: css, hover

I downloaded a CSS Menu from [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) and trying to make some changes, here is fiddle file [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4uL6/3/) and the [full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/h4uL6/3/embedded/result/) result.

Now I trying to do 2 things:

- Make `Logo` text/image not to have hover
- Fix the width, I put 100% but if you look at full screen result you will notice what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 42 to: `#navbar li:not(:first-child):hover {`

This will make sure the hover effect is not applied to the first `<li>` which in your case contains the logo. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwV4q/)

This is called [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

To fix your nav position use:

```
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0px;
}
```

**EDIT:** if you still want the little margin on each side use:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    left: 1%; /* you can change this to whatever margin you like */
    right: 1%;
}
```

and add:

```
#navbar {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you solved my first problem, what about second problem? why 100% width not working properly?

Comment: This small space on the left was not problem, the right part of the bar is the problem, the end of bar is beyond the page. You need to see the full screen to see it.

Comment: It fixes both. if you still want the little margin on each side use the edit

Comment: It should not end like this, put the width to 90% to see the shape.

Comment: I see the rounded corners.. can you link to a print screen of how it looks after using the EDIT?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention: `#navbar` should have `width:auto` instead of `width:100%` for the edit to work. let me know if it did the trick

Comment: #navbar>li:first-child~li:hover makes more sense. It's not CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Try `#navbar>li:first-child~li:hover`. I updated your fiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/h4uL6/7/

If you do need a fixed position for some reason, wrap the entire code in a `<div>`, `position:absolute;` it and give it the same width and margins as I gave `#nav` to this `<div>` then make `#nav`'s `position:fixed;`.